# Why would link order matter with extern variables?

Tags: c, extern

Once upon a time, my teacher at school showed some example of code with question "What will be the output?". It was something like this:

file1.c (just one line):

```
int a = 8;
```

file2.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int b = 20;
    extern int a;
    printf("%d", a + b);
}
```

Then, he compiled this two times: the first was something like this:

```
gcc file1.c file2.c -o prog_name
```

and the output was I guess `28`; but then, he compiled in this way (or similar to this):

```
gcc file2.c file1.c -o prog_name
```

and the result was just different, I think it was `20`.

Now, when I want to reproduce this "tricky question" I'm only getting `28` as the result, using these two different(?) methods to compile. I want to simply ask if this is order of source files when compiling matters and how to reproduce this example to working that as I remember it was. Is this even possible?

Comment: Ask the teacher instead, clearly your memory of this is far too hazy.

Comment: You are getting the correct, expected behaviour.  Link order should not affect the output of the program — within broad limits.  (If a pair of libraries implement a common function in different ways, then link order of both libraries would matter, but that's way more complex than what you're dealing with.)

Comment: @HansPassant He's dead now.

Comment: My ouija board says to google "static initialization order fiasco".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the correct, expected behaviour. Link order should not affect the output of the program — within broad limits. (If a pair of libraries implement a common function in different ways, then if you link with both libraries, the link order of the libraries would matter, but that's way more complex than what you're dealing with.)

I recommend forgetting about the alternative behaviour since the originator is no longer available to be consulted.

Comment: I think you gave a good point, but I wanted to ask anyway to be sure that this is impossible :) I'll wait a bit more and then accept this answer.